# ReactJS Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Why am I getting this error below? My statement `ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);` is 100% legit code.

My github repo: https://github.com/leongaban/react_starwars

[image]

The app.js file

```
import react from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import App from 'components/App'

require('index.html');

// Create app
const container = document.getElementById('app-container');

// Render app
ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

The components/App file

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () =>
  <div className='container'>
    <div className='row'>

    </div>
    <div className='row'>

    </div>
  </div>;

export default App;
```

My webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: [
  './src/app.js'
],
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
  filename: 'app.bundle.js',
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
    },
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  ],
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
]
};
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);` is not valid JS.. You can only use that inside a .JSX File.

Comment: @xDreamCoding You can use it in a JS file as long as the JSX is transpiled to pure JS...

Comment: You'll want the REGEX for your loader test to also include a .js extension along with a .jsx. It may look like this: ```/\.(js|jsx)$/```, This will make sure that Webpack transpiles your app.js file as well as all of your source code.

Comment: You've got lots of things wrong here. React should be capitalized on import, Dom in ReactDom should be capitalized. No need to import `index.html`. Also, your component import path should be `./components/App`. Next, you have to setup your Babel presets to transpile your code, `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-react`.

Comment: @MichaelLyons `/\.jsx?$` matches both .js and .jsx... the question mark is present

Comment: @AndrewLi Oh so my regex is redundant then. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this as your webpack config file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
    ],
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
]
};
```

You are missing the presets

Comment: Thanks! This was it... I was following a tutorial from an older project. My newer React projects worked fine so it was the older outdated webpack.config I was using. And like others have said, I had miss-capitalized some of my imports. Thank you! I fixed the app with this more modern webpack.config and renamed my imports now it works. 3 more mins!

Comment: actually now with webpack 2 module.loader is been deprecated in favour of module.rules

Comment: Which one is the equivalent of presets: ['es2015', 'react'] regarding babel 7?

Comment: I am using .babelrc it works on another app but not working in the other one.

Answer (score 18):

I was getting the same error, and I simply needed to add a .babelrc file to the route of the project (same location as package.json) containing the following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env", 
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This was it for me, but I had to change `env` to `@babel/env`, and `react` to `react-app`. I'm using a project with Create React App + TypeScript + Rescripts (https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts)

Answer (score 5):

Install babel-preset-react for jsx syntax.

```
npm install babel-preset-react
```

presets

```
loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can put your presets in .babelrc file in the root of your project. Of course you need to install it first.

Like this
`/path/to/your/project/.babelrc`

`{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}`

Answer (score 3):

Add `.babelrc` in the root folder with the following, and make sure it is 'presets' no 'preset'

```
{
    "presets" : ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

here is my `webpack.config.js` for reference:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: ["@babel/env"]}
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']},
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/',
        hotOnly: true
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
}
```

Babel-loader v8 need @babel v7 to work
`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `resolve` property to your webpack config file:

```
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This is NOT the problem. Webpack already resolves .js by default.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is working with CRA and get this error. Here the solution goes.

Goto `package.json` and add `babel` config. If I'm not seeming so generous, below is the code

```
 "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react-app"
        ]
 }
```

Keep rest of CRA setup as it is. Actually CRA uses it's own custom preset `react-app` and that's what is setup in `webpack.config.js` file. Hence no need for other presets.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and none of the above answers helped.

I had a symbolically linked folder-- my code was on D:/Code but I was running from C:/Code via the symbolic link.

One of the js packages was recognizing the link and attempting to run within D and failing.

I had to open the code from D: and not from the symbolic link path, and the problem went away.