# error in react project after moving to another machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am new to react 
I am using webpack with babel loader in my react app

my project was running fine till i have changed my machine I have copied all the file except `node_modules`(installed it with `npm install`)

when i have tried to run or build project it is giving me error at the  while this is running at the old machine correctly

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app.js';
import {HashRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'


ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>

, document.getElementById('app'));
```

> Rs-MacBook-Pro:intra rd$ npm start
>
> > boilerplate-intranet@1.0.0 start /Users/rd/Documents/intra
> >     webpack-dev-server --open --mode development
>
> ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/ ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack
>   output is served from / ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served
>   from /Users/rd/Documents/intra/public ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to
>   /index.html ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: / ✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash:
>   53cc551e031b5ed39d70 Version: webpack 4.19.1 Time: 3596ms Built at:
>   2018-09-21 12:44:47
>       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names bundle.js  836 KiB    main  [emitted]  main Entrypoint main = bundle.js
>   [./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js] 135 bytes {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/punycode/punycode.js] 14.3 KiB {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built] [0] multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js 40
>   bytes {main} [built] [./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js] 177
>   KiB {main} [built] [./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes
>   {main} [built] [./node_modules/url/util.js] 314 bytes {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.78 KiB {main}
>   [built] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^./log$] (webpack)/hot sync
>   nonrecursive ^./log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75
>   bytes {main} [built] [./src/index.js] 761 bytes {main} [built]
>   [failed] [1 error]
>       + 11 hidden modules
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token (9:4)
>
> 7 |     8 | ReactDOM.render(
>
> > 9 |     
> >          |     ^   10 |            11 |        12 |
>
> @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   ./src/index.js main[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM1mk.png) ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ReactDOM.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267369/reactjs-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-reactdom-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some version of babel-core and babel-loader aren't compatible together, try to update them to latest version if you don't mind to have a specific version

```js
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```