# Poblem Gulp using React and JSX

Tags: reactjs, gulp, jsx

Hi guys I have a problem when I try to launch the command "gulp" from Terminal.

My gulpfile.js is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default',function() {

    console.log("Io sto per imparare ad usare React.js");

}); 
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');


gulp.task('default', function() {

        return browserify('./source/app.js')
                   .transform(babelify)
                     .bundle()
                     .pipe(source('snapterest.js'))
                     .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));

});
```

and When i try to launch the 'gulp' command:

[image]

My app.js file is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Application = require('./components/Application.react');

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('react-application'));
```

I am very grateful if someone can help me to find out a solution.

Comment: This will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267369/reactjs-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-reactdom-render

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ReactDOM.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267369/reactjs-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-reactdom-render)

Comment: But I cannot fint a webpack.config file in my project. How can I add one?

Comment: If that's the solution you need, just create the webpack.config file in the root. ReactJS uses Webpack as part of the build so it should just pull it in if it exists.