# ReactJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ReactDOM.render with WebPack 4, Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am following simple tutorials like https://github.com/YaroslavW/react-min-setup-abc to create a new React application from scratch (using webpack 4 and babel 7 instead of create-react-app from react-scripts).

I am getting the same error as [ReactJS Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ReactDOM.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267369/reactjs-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-reactdom-render) (Sorry for possible duplicate but none of the solutions from this thread are working for me).

```
SyntaxError: C:\...\src\index.js: Unexpected token (7:2)

   5 |
   6 | ReactDOM.render(
>  7 |   <div>{title}</div>,
     |   ^
   8 |   document.getElementById('app')
   9 | );
```

Seems that this repo was working fine but suddenly became broken. I haven't done any changes after pulling from the github. Many tutorials also lead to the same code and the same error.

Seems the solution should be adding `@babel/preset-react` to the `.babelrc` file but it is already there in the repo.

Are new versions of the toolset not compatible with eath other or is there any misconfiguration in the repo?

I am using Windows 10 x64, Nodejs 10.16.3 abd Npm 6.9.0. Other libraries are unchanged from the repo.

**Important information**: the issue can only be reproduced when running node.js commands from a Windows symbolic linked path (e.g. using mklink command).

Answer (score -1):

Seems I found the issue and fixed it. It is surely a bug in Windows 10 affecting filesystem operations... Even using an undocumented feature or a hack.

I had the repo in a symbolic linked directory (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) and completely forgot about it after several years of having this link. A big C/C++ project is located there and link makes no issues with the C/C++ toolchain.

So when I run node commands from a symbolic path the error occurs.
When I use the source path (without any links) the error is gone.

I am leaving this here as this may be a very rare case which could be a huge time sink to find the issue if anyone is running node commands from such a linked directory and forced to use Windows by some reason.